# Laravel HasManyThrough via many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following Models:

- Students
- Groups
- Assignments

Students and Groups have a many-to-many relationship

Groups to Assignments is a one-to-many relationship

I would like to get a student's assignments using eloquent. My initial thought was to use the hasManyThrough relationship, but that won't work because of the many-to-many relationship between groups and students.

Is there an eloquent solution for this or will I need to write something of my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Build your models as follows:

```
// Sample Eloquent Model for Students
class Student extends Model
{

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Group::class);
    }

    public function assignments()
    {
        $assignments = [];
        foreach($this->groups as $group)
        {
            array_push($assignments, ...$group->assignments);
        }
        return $assignments;
    }
}

// Sample Eloquent Model for Groups
class Group extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function assignments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Assignment::class);
    }
}

// Sample Eloquent Model for Assignments
class Assignment extends Model
{
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
}
```

And if you want to get students assignments:

```
$assignments = $student->assignments();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the relationship between the Student and Group models both be BelongsToMany?